# How to write mindful minutes to HealthKit?

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm trying to write mindful minutes to the health app ,but I get the error :

> _HKObjectValidationFailureException', reason: 'Value 2 is not compatible with type HKCategoryTypeIdentifierMindfulSession

This is my function , amount is a double

```
func writeMindful() {

        if let mindfulType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: .mindfulSession) {

            let mindfullSample = HKCategorySample(type: mindfulType, value: Int(amount), start: Date(), end: Date() + amount)

            // at the end, we save it
            healthStore.save(mindfullSample, withCompletion: { (success, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    // something happened
                    return
                }

                if success {
                    print("My new data was saved in HealthKit")

                } else {
                    // something happened again
                }

            })

        }


    }
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 4):

In code documentation of `HKCategorySample` we can see:

> ```
> /**
>  @property   value
>  @discussion The preferred enum for the value is determined by the receiver's category type.
>  */
> open var value: Int { get }
> ```

It means, that every category has its own enum for values. MindfullSession has [this enum](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategorytypeidentifier/1648575-mindfulsession) with only one applicable value: `HKCategoryValue.notApplicable`.

So your code should looks like this:

`let mindfullSample = HKCategorySample(type: mindfulType, value: HKCategoryValue.notApplicable.rawValue, start: Date(), end: Date() + amount)`

Comment: but when I use this only 0 gets saved and amount is not 0

Comment: By `amount` did you mean `amount of minutes`?